# How to get back to same page after server side processing?

Tags: struts

Thinking that , in struts 1.2, say a function public ActionForward abc(){ return null;} will return to the same page.
But i got this exception.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:441)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)

How to get into the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In struts-config.xml, write a forward tag inside your action tag like this.

```
<action ...>
<forward name = "samePage" path="..."/>
</action>
```

Now, in your code use

```
mapping.findForward("samePage");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
return mapping.getInputForward();
```